# Consume a JSON feed into proper Ruby

Tags: ruby, json, hash

I am currently consuming an api feed into a ruby on rails project. Being new to Ruby I don't feel that I am consuming and managing the JSON properly. There are a few features which are not working and I believe they revolve around how I'm treating the JSON object once I have it. Here is what I am working with.

```
{ "auth" : {
    "person" : {
        "id" : 1,
        "name" : "john",
        "pass" : "123"
    },
    "person" : {
        "id" : 2,
        "name" : "fred",
        "pass" : "789"
    }
}}
```

I find I can get a simple array by doing:

```
jsonArray = JSON.parse(persons)
# the following allows me to target the persons objects
personArray = jsonArray["auth"]["persons"]
```

The problem here is attempting to do something like `personArray.first(5)` gives me int to string conversion errors. I'd like to get this into a workable hash, something I can do operations off of, but currently it seems I can only iterate over it as a hash.  I may need to sort, pull persons out of, and do other operations to this result data. How should I be correctly importing this?

Comment: Note that `jsonArray` in your Ruby code above is NOT an [`Array`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html); it's a [`Hash`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html). Calling a JavaScript `object` an "associative array" leads to this sort of sloppy terminology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually direct parsing your json string wouldn't give you `["auth"]["persons"]`. There is no `"persons"` field inside the json string......I hope that's a typo error.

The exact format you need in order to make `personArray.first(5)` to work should be:

```
{
  "auth": {
    "persons": [ # Note the square bracket here, which defines an array instead of a hash
      {"id": 1, "name": "john", "pass": "123"},
      {"id": 2, "name": "fred", "pass": "789"}
    ]
  }
}
```

and you could do what you wanted to do now.

Comment: Yes, that was a typo, thanks for the note. I hadn't noticed the bracket/brace issue. This is an API which I was not able to design, but may be able to work with the provider. It would make much more sense to treat the persons as an array rather than distinct objects. I'll test this out and will mark this if it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON above results in a JS object storing less data than you think it has. You are overwriting the `person` key repeatedly. Try copy/pasting this into the console of your web browser:

```js
var o = { "auth" : {
  "person" : {
    "id" : 1,
    "name" : "john",
    "pass" : "123"
  },
  "person" : {
    "id" : 2,
    "name" : "fred",
    "pass" : "789"
  }
}};

JSON.stringify(o);
// '{"auth":{"person":{"id":2,"name":"fred","pass":"789"}}}'
```